# haproxy frontend cur sessions never decreases

Tags: redirect, nginx, frontend, haproxy, captiveportal

We got a strange behavior with haproxy for one website : frontends current sessions never decreases.

[haproxy-frontend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7Q57.png)

So, limits are reached after 3 or 4 days, and we have to restart haproxy to reset active connections.

Backend servers is a simple nginx with php7. Here is haproxy conf :

```
global
    log /dev/log    local0
    log /dev/log    local1 notice
    chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 666 level user
    stats timeout 30s
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    daemon
    maxconn 50000

    ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
    crt-base /etc/ssl/private

    ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS
    ssl-default-bind-options no-tls-tickets no-sslv3
    ssl-default-server-ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
    ssl-default-server-options no-sslv3 no-tlsv10 no-tlsv11 no-tls-tickets
tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048

defaults
    log         global
    mode        http
    option httplog
    option dontlognull
    option dontlog-normal
    option forwardfor
    option redispatch
    retries 3
    compression algo gzip
    compression type text/html text/plain text/css text/javascript application/javascript 
    timeout     connect     4s
    timeout     client      10s
    timeout     server      30s
    timeout     http-keep-alive 500
    timeout http-request    30s
    errorfile   400   /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
    errorfile   403   /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
    errorfile   408   /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
    errorfile   500   /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
    errorfile   502   /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
    errorfile   503   /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
    errorfile   504   /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http

frontend splash-frontend
    mode http
    maxconn 20000
    bind xx.xx.xx.xx:80
    redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc }
    bind xx.xx.xx.xx:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/certs/splash.domain.net.pem alpn h2,http/1.1
    default_backend splash-backend
    http-response set-header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000

backend splash-backend
    balance roundrobin
    mode http
    server splash1 xx.xx.xx.xx:443 check inter 1000 ssl verify none
    server splash2 xx.xx.xx.xx:443 check inter 1000 ssl verify none
    server splash3 xx.xx.xx.xx:443 check inter 1000 ssl verify none
```

Then, nginx conf for servers :

```
user www-data www-data;
worker_processes 2;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;
worker_rlimit_nofile 1024;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 512;
}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    sendfile "on";
    tcp_nopush "on";
    tcp_nodelay "on";
    keepalive_timeout "5";
    access_log "/var/log/nginx/access.log";
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log error;
    server_tokens off;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    upstream php-handler {
        server 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443 default ssl http2;
        server_name splash.domain.net;
        root /var/www/domain.net/splash;
        include /etc/nginx/ssl.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/errors.conf;
        error_log syslog:server=xx.xx.xx.xx:11514 notice;
        access_log syslog:server=xx.xx.xx.xx:11514,tag=nginx,severity=info;
        location / {
          index           index.php;
          try_files       $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri&$args;
        }

        location ~* \.(img|css|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|map)$  {
          deny            all;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
          fastcgi_pass    php-handler;
          fastcgi_index   index.php;
          include         /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
          fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
          fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
          proxy_cache     off;
          expires         -1;
        }

    }

}
```

And finaly, the web page source :

```html
<?php $redirectURL = isset($_GET['loginurl']) && $_GET['loginurl'] ? $_GET['loginurl'] : 'http://captiveportal.domain.net'; ?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Chargement...</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache">
        <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
        <noscript><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; url=<?php echo $redirectURL; ?>"></noscript>
        <style>html{width: 100%;height: 100%;}body {margin: 0 auto;padding: 20px;width: auto;overflow-y: none;font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif;font-weight: 400;color: #777;text-align: center;}a {text-decoration: none;color: #777;}.content {padding: 15px;overflow: hidden;}.centered {position: absolute;top: 50%;left: 50%;transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);}.load-wrap{text-align: center;}.radio {display: inline-block;width: 180px;height: 180px;}</style>
        <script type="text/javascript">function onLoad() { window.setTimeout( function(){ window.location = "<?php echo $redirectURL; ?>"; }, 2000 ); }</script>
    </head>
    <body onload="onLoad();">
        <div class="content">
            <a href="<?php echo $redirectURL; ?>">
                <div class="centered">
                    <h3>Loading ...</p>
                </div>
             </a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Our context, is that users are behind a captive portal, and the process is :

1 - Users requests to internet are intercepted by captive portal, and redirected to the splash page described above.

2a - If the the splash page is launched with a browser, there is a javascript or meta redirect to the captive portal website, to let users accept terms and connect to internet.

2b - If the splash page is requested by background or non interactive app, process stop here

We dont have any problem with other websites we manage with haproxy, but our splash page continuesly increase current connections, and this is a real problem. We've tried many things, without success like : 
- option server-http-close
- option forceclose

With no effects on this webpage ! We need some help, because there is probably one thing we don't understand. Anyone have an idea ?